# Kubernetes: How to setup Promtail as a sidecar in order to read custom log paths

Tags: kubernetes, logging, grafana, grafana-loki, promtail

Does anyone know how to configure Promtail to watch and tail custom log paths in a Kubernetes pod? I have a deployment that creates customized log files in a directory like so `/var/log/myapp`. I found some documentation [here](https://github.com/jafernandez73/grafana-loki/blob/master/docs/promtail-setup.md) that says to deploy Promtail as a sidecar to the container you want to collect logs from. I was hoping someone could explain how this method works in practice. Does it need to be done as a sidecar or could it be done as a Daemonset? Or if you have alternative solution that has proven to work could please show me an example.

Comment: you can find useful Medium article with an example of Sidecar: https://medium.com/bb-tutorials-and-thoughts/kubernetes-learn-sidecar-container-pattern-6d8c21f873d

Comment: @WytrzymałyWiktor I found this helm chart to be useful in getting it to work: https://github.com/giantswarm/simple-logger

Answer (score 1):

Posting comment as the community wiki answer for better visibility:

---

*Below information is taken from README.md from the GitHun repo provided by atlee19:*

**This docs assume**:

- you have loki and grafana already deployed. Please refered to official documentation for installation
- The logfile you want to scrape is in JSON format

This Helm chart deploy a application pod with 2 containers: - a Golang app writing logs in a separate file. - a Promtail that read that log file and send it to loki.

The file path can be updated via the [./helm/values.yaml](https://github.com/giantswarm/simple-logger/blob/master/helm/values.yaml) file.

`sidecar.labels` is a map where you can add the labels that will be added to your log entry in Loki.

Example:

- `Logfile` located at `/home/slog/creator.log`
- Adding labels

  - `job: promtail-sidecar`
  - `test: golang`

```
sidecar:
  logfile:
    path: /home/slog
    filename: creator.log
  labels:
    job: promtail-sidecar
    test: golang
```