# Kubernetes: Is it possible to add an existing deployment as a sidecar to another deployment?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, rancher, k3s, sidecar

I have a helm chart that I was going to deploy and I would like to use the deployment it creates as a sidecar for another deployment. Is this possible using the Rancher's GUI or is it something that I can directly configure in the YAML?

Comment: This doesn't seem like something that's possible in general; picking the containers off of one Deployment and adding them to another.  Maybe with actual code calling the Kubernetes API, but not with deployment tools like Helm.  Why do you want a sidecar here?

Comment: Mainly in part of this question I was asking https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69730689/kubernetes-how-to-setup-promtail-as-a-sidecar-in-order-to-read-custom-log-paths

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR:** No

---

Not really possible. You have to specify multiple containers in the same pod/deployment manifest to create sidecars. Like this:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: webserver
spec:
  volumes:
    - name: shared-logs
      emptyDir: {}

  containers:
    - name: nginx
      image: nginx
      volumeMounts:
        - name: shared-logs
          mountPath: /var/log/nginx

    - name: sidecar-container
      image: busybox
      command: ["sh","-c","while true; do cat /var/log/nginx/access.log /var/log/nginx/error.log; sleep 30; done"]
      volumeMounts:
        - name: shared-logs
          mountPath: /var/log/nginx
```

---

Alternatively, you can achieve this by using [Admission Controllers](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/admission-controllers/), the same way Istio does, but this is way outside of the scope of this question.